# Going in the right direction for a Data Structures class project?

Tags: java

Having an issue programming the event handling of this class.  Do not understand how to implement it in the GUI class.  This is not an graded assignment or has to be handed in.  This is simply some independent exercises to help with Java coding.  Here is some description of the problem asked:

**Create a Java GUI program which has one button, one text box and one textfield. When a user click on the button, the system should pop up a file selection window, which allows the user to select a file from the hard disk. After the file is selected, e.g., “ssn.txt”, your program should read input file “ssn.txt”. Inside the file each line represents a social security number.
The program first read all the ssns into the memory. If the format of a ssn is wrong in the file, your program should throw a SSNException object, and catch that Exception object, and display an error message for that line in text box.**

Here is some of my code:

```
public class SSN_GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public SSN_GUI(){

    makeObject();
    doTheLayout();
    theButton.addActionListener(this);

    }
    private JTextField inputSSN;
    private JButton theButton; 

    //Make all the Objects
    private void makeObject(){

        inputSSN = new JTextField(15);
        inputSSN.setEditable(true);
        theButton = new JButton();

        }

    //Layout all the Objects
    private void doTheLayout(){

        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
        thePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        thePanel.add(new JLabel("Enter Social Security Number: "));
        thePanel.add(inputSSN, "Center");
        thePanel.add(theButton, "North");
    }

    // Handle the button push
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    }


}
```

Comment: you should try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why don't you try it and then see what does or does not work? If you are looking for a code review you should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks good so far. You'll eventually have to put this into a JFrame and make it visible on the screen. I take it that the "problems" in the title doesn't refer to any particular problem you are having, just that you're working on some programming problems for your course?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only code you are showing us is building the GUI layout and components. All the complexity of this assignment sounds like it is in the file IO and the SSN validation. If you want to know if you are building the GUI correctly, it looks fine so far. If you want help with the file IO and SSN validation, try some stuff yourself and update your question to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I'm truly sorry that your "data structures" professor thinks anything in Swing belongs in his/her course. This project sounds like it belongs in a CS101 (perhaps 102) course for basic programming concepts.

Comment: In the future, you should consider a better title to your question.  "Java Programming Problems" is mightily unspecific.  I'll edit it.

Comment: These are problems that I am trying on my own to be a better programmer.  I havent taken Java on awhile just need to brush up on my programming skills.

Comment: Sorry about the title.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I've updated my post.  I need help understanding how to implement the event handling for my class.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have a GUI and your doing something with data you should probably take the MVC approach. Thus you could split the GUI event handling and the data processing into two different classes.

I would have a class that extends JFrame which will be responsible for showing the view. Your view (although not best practice) would create a new model class which will have your file reading and validation methods.

Note: Your problem statement does not indicate what the text field is going to be used for.

You should have an SSNException which extends Throwable. You could add other fields but I would just add a field to contain the malformed SSN as a String. You could also add a zero-argument constructor to set a default error message.

You could create a model class that would be responsible for iterating over each line in a file and running a validation method which throws an SSNException. An easy way to validate the SSN would be to use regular expressions. Otherwise you can use a more primitive approach such as validating the string character by character. An SSN can only have 9 digits (thus 9 characters in length) in the form of `###-##-####`. As such a valid SSN could only have numbers 0 - 9 at positions 0-2, 4-5, 7-10 with the characters at position 3 and 6 being a '-'.

If you decide to employ a regular expression use `[String Reference].matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")` in a validation method that `throws SSNException` in the method signature. When the match method returns false you can throw a new SSNException up the call stack.

In terms of storing the SSN's read in you could use an ArrayList or make your own ArrayList class. If the input file contains an integer at the top of the file then a primitive `String[]` array would do just fine. Assuming the data file has a simple data structure in which each line represents one SSN, ready to go Java libraries for file reading include `java.util.Scanner` and `java.io.FileReader`. As such you can use `new FileReader(filename)` pass it to the Scanner. Use a while `.hasNextLine()` loop.